"De Luna en Luna irá"
Quisiera preguntar sobre el significado de “de luna en luna irá” en
“Mil años pasarán
Y el duende de tu nombre
De Luna en Luna irá
Aullando fuerte woh, woh, woh”
No he podido encontrar la construcción gramática de “de ... en ...” en línea. No sé si la he buscado correctamente. Creo que “de” significa “from” en este caso y “en” siginifica “in” o “on” en inglés.
Y supongo que el verbo “irá” se refiere al labo yendo a la luna, ¿no es así?
Creo que la antedicha frase la he interpretado malísimo. Ayúdenme, por favor. ¡Muchas gracias!

Uf sobran ejemplos para eso, como ‘ir de mal en peor’, de X en X quiere decir que vas saltando y cayendo sobre cada X que encuentres. La pregunta es poesía, o sea va a estar difícil para analizar esa metáfora del duende acá.

Hola, ¿entonces se trata de saltar de una luna y luego caer en la misma? Muchas gracias

NOOOOO, no es eso! Se trata de saltar de una luna y luego caer en otra luna. Después, saltás desde la otra luna y caés en otra luna nueva. Y así sucesivamente. Como una rana que va saltando las piedritas (de piedra en piedra) para cruzar de un lado del río al otro.

Ah ~ ¡ya! Muchas gracias por la aclaración :).

Dado que, al menos en la Tierra, hay una sola luna, "irá aullando de luna en luna" significa "irá aullando de una a otra noche/noche tras noche (con luna)".
Claramente, la oración hace referencia a la leyenda según la cual el hombre lobo aúlla cuando hay luna llena.
"Irá" no es un verbo de movimiento referido a "de luna en luna", sino que forma perífrasis verbal con "aullando".
